# Javascript Math results not correct

Tags: javascript, math

I'm working with Javascript and noticing it return some weird values.

---

`12194 / (10^8)`

- Google = 0.00012194
- Desktop Calc = 0.00012194
- Javascript = 6097

`121945000000 / (10^8)`

- Google = 1,219.45
- Desktop Calc = 1,219.45
- Javascript = 60972500000

---

Am I doing something wrong here or is this an issue with Javascript numbers?

Comment: `^` in JavaScript is not exponentiation, but XOR.

Comment: Use double-asterisk ( ** )if you want exponential in JavaScript.  ``12194 / (10**8)`` will give you **0.00012194**.

Comment: It's almost as if 10^8==2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` is the XOR operator in javascript. Refer to [Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR)

You should use either [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) or [**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation)

```js
console.log(12194 / Math.pow(10, 8))
console.log(121945000000 / Math.pow(10, 8))
```

```js
console.log(12194 / (10 ** 8))
console.log(121945000000 / (10 ** 8))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the ^ in JavaScript for equations.

Instead, you can use `12194 / Math.pow(10, 8)`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp